# How can I search a nvarchar field to see if there are any lower case characters in the value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to query my SQL Server 2000 database to see if some of my columns contain lower case values.

For example, if a column contains the value `THIS IS VALID` then this is valid. If the column value is `THIS IS VALID I Snuck In lol: SOME VALUES` then this is not valid and would like to return the row.

I really don't want to do this manually because it would be quite error prone, time consuming (50k rows) and 20 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
where YourCol LIKE '%[a-z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Comment: Except there are 20 columns, so need to add additional columns to where clause (either manually or by generating the sql)

Comment: So you need to write it 20 times then. You can query `syscolumns` to generate dynamic SQL.

Comment: Writing the same query 20 times is really not a problem. Especially since it is this easy to do what I want.